# Loop through querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

I've got a function to close a modal when clicking anywhere outside of it. This is the code
JS:

```
var modal = document.querySelectorAll('.quickview-modal')
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
modal.forEach(function() {
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    $('.item').removeClass('modal-carousel-fix');
    $('.modal-backdrop').css('display','none')
    $('.quickview-modal').css('display','none');
    $(this).parent().closest('.carousel-inner').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  }
 }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="modal quickview-modal" id="quickViewModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But this doesn't seem to work. 
If I change it to

```
var modal = document.querySelector('.quickview-modal')
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    $('.item').removeClass('modal-carousel-fix');
    $('.modal-backdrop').css('display','none')
    $('.quickview-modal').css('display','none');
    $(this).parent().closest('.carousel-inner').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  }
 }
```

It works on the first `.quickview-modal` object, so I'm assuming something is wrong with the loop. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Yes, there is something wrong with the loop, you are re-assigning `window.onclick` over and over, and you are comparing an HTMLElement (event.target)  to a HTMLCollection (modal)

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll` doesn't return a real array, to convert it to one simply use `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll())`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @SebastianSpeitel says in a comment above

> document.querySelectorAll doesn't return a real array

That's true. It returns `NodeList` or `HTMLCollection`, but you can still map it with `.forEach`, so that's not the real issue.

The @Luca's comment provides a solution.

> you are re-assigning window.onclick over and over, and you are comparing an HTMLElement (event.target) to a HTMLCollection

So to make easier for the author of this question I wrote the following code:

```
// modal is a list of elements
var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.quickview-modal')
modals.forEach(function(modal) {
  // modal is the current element
  modal.onclick = function(e) {
    $('.item').removeClass('modal-carousel-fix');
    $('.modal-backdrop').css('display','none')
    $('.quickview-modal').css('display','none');
    $(this).parent().closest('.carousel-inner').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  }
});
```

But using `addEventListener` is definitely better practise. So consider using it like this: `modal.addEventListener("click", function callback(e) {})`, where `click` can be replaced with other events (hover, keypress, ect..)

Also even better JQuery solution will be to use `$(document).on('click', '.YOURCLASS', function)`

```
$(document).on('click', '.quickview-modal', function (e) {
    // The same code as the onclick above, OR
    $(this).css('display','none');
    $(this).parent().closest('.carousel-inner').css('overflow','hidden');
});
```

Comment: You should probably use the function `.addEventListener()` instead of assigning a function to the `onclick` property

Comment: @Luca, yeah. I just wanted to use the style of the author and show him a solution, so he can understand it. But yeah it will be even better for him to know to use `addEventListener`, so I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("body").on("click", ".quickview-modal", function() {
    $(this).css('display','none');
    $(this).parent().closest('.carousel-inner').css('overflow','hidden');
});
```